# Toggle all td's class in column on checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I'm looking for solution, 
I have table with checkboxes at the top of each selected columns.
I want to make click all td's in "checked" column by one checkbox click.

fiddle so far:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var hmc = row.find(':checkbox:checked').length;
  row.find('td.counter').text(hmc);
});

$("td.zero").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("zero2")) {
    $(this).removeClass("zero2");
    var row3 = $(this).closest('tr');
    var wal4 = $(this).text();
    var wal5 = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.counter2').text();
    wal6 = parseFloat(wal5, 10) - parseFloat(wal4, 10);
    row3.find('td.counter2').text(wal6.toFixed(2));


  } else {

    $(this).addClass("zero2");

    var row2 = $(this).closest('tr');
    var wal = $(this).text();
    var wal2 = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.counter2').text();
    wal3 = parseFloat(wal, 10) + parseFloat(wal2, 10);
    row2.find('td.counter2').text(wal3.toFixed(2));

  }

});

$(':checkbox.taker').on('change', function(e) {
  alert("tds in column clicked");
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  cursor: default;
}

input.ptaszek {
  transform: scale(2);
}

td.zero2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>X</th>
         <th>X</th>
         <th>X</th>
         <th>Count1</th>
         <th>Count2</th>
         <th>Count3</th>
         <th>Val1</th>
         <th>Val2</th>
         <th>Val3</th>
         <th>Val4</th>
         <th>Val5</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
         <td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
         <td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
         <td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
         <td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div>
         </td>
         <td class='counter'>0</td>
         <td class='counter2'>0</td>
         <td class='counter3'>0</td>
         <td class='zero'>0.5</td>
         <td class='zero'>5</td>
         <td class='zero'>2.1</td>
         <td class='zero'>0.2</td>
         <td class='zero'>1.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div>
         </td>
         <td class='counter'>0</td>
         <td class='counter2'>0</td>
         <td class='counter3'>0</td>
         <td class='zero'>1.4</td>
         <td class='zero'>0.5</td>
         <td class='zero'>2</td>
         <td class='zero'>1.1</td>
         <td class='zero'>1.5</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

It's working for individual td click now, I need to make "bulk" click all td's by checkbox check ;)

Anyone have ideas?
Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Can you explain the problem even more, if you click the row checkbox what should happen? please explain clearly and what is the problem currently?

Comment: If I click COLUMN checkbox, all td's in selected column  (for example: Val2) should be clicked/toggled.

I mean these small checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on comments updating answer.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Does this help you?

**Logic:**

Check if the checkbox is checked, if its checked then assign all the respective elements as selected, no matter if they are selected or unselected already and vice versa for unselected, thus the end user will be able to select/unselect all the columns if he uses the checkbox!

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var hmc = row.find(':checkbox:checked').length;
  row.find('td.counter').text(hmc);
});

$("td.zero").on("click", function () {
 if ( $( this ).hasClass( "zero2" ) ) {
 $(this).removeClass("zero2");
var row3 = $(this).closest('tr');
var wal4 = $(this).text();
var wal5 = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.counter2').text();
wal6 = parseFloat(wal5, 10) - parseFloat(wal4, 10);
row3.find('td.counter2').text(wal6.toFixed(2));


      } else {

$(this).addClass("zero2");

var row2 = $(this).closest('tr');
var wal = $(this).text();
var wal2 = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.counter2').text();
wal3 = parseFloat(wal, 10) + parseFloat(wal2, 10);
row2.find('td.counter2').text(wal3.toFixed(2));

}
      
      });
      
$(':checkbox.taker').on('change', function(e) { 
  var elem = $(this).parent().index(); 
  $('tr').each(function(index){
    var td = $(this).children().eq(elem);
    if(index > 1){
      if($(':checkbox.taker:checked').length > 0){
        td.addClass('zero2');
      }else{
        td.removeClass('zero2');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td
{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  cursor: default;
}
input.ptaszek {
  transform: scale(2);
}

td.zero2{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>X</th><th>X</th><th>X</th>
<th>Count1</th><th>Count2</th><th>Count3</th>
<th>Val1</th><th>Val2</th><th>Val3</th><th>Val4</th><th>Val5</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='taker'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div></td>
<td><div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div></td>
<td><div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div></td>
<td class='counter'>0</td><td class='counter2'>0</td><td class='counter3'>0</td>
<td class='zero'>0.5</td><td class='zero'>5</td><td class='zero'>2.1</td><td class='zero'>0.2</td><td class='zero'>1.7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div></td>
<td><div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div></td>
<td><div><input type='checkbox' name='chkboxarray' class='ptaszek'></div></td>
<td class='counter'>0</td><td class='counter2'>0</td><td class='counter3'>0</td>
<td class='zero'>1.4</td><td class='zero'>0.5</td><td class='zero'>2</td><td class='zero'>1.1</td><td class='zero'>1.5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not bad but now.. I also need to call function which will get and increase (when toggled) and decrease (when untoggled) by value from toggled cells to "Count2" cell. 
When I'm clicing single td's It's working good, when I'm using checkboxes to bulk toggle whole column it's also working but only for one column, when I will check two columns and uncheck one of them, "Count2" value increasing instead of decreasing by toggled cell value.

Any way to fix that?


updated by your solution and moved to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lqr5LkL/5/

Comment: @KrystianK Updated my answer

Comment: Ok, now increasing/decreasing is working perfect but.. still when I will check more than one column checkboxes and try to deselect one of them, checkbox is unchecking but cells and 'Count2' values don't change.

Comment: @KrystianK Sorry I am not your Unit tester, please figure it out yourself!